# Сomplete homogeneous space which is not locally compact

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry

It is well-known theorem that every locally compact, homogeneous, metric space is complete.
Does anybody know example of complete, homogeneous, metric space which is not locally compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Banach space is homogeneous since the metric is arising from a norm. An infinite dimensional Banach space has the property that its unit ball is not compact; therefore the space is not locally compact.

For a concrete example, take the space of continuous real functions on an interval with the supremum norm.

Comment: What is $\alpha x$ for a metric space? I think that "homogeneous" means that the isometry group is transitive. Anyway, Banach spaces are homogeneous.

Comment: @Sergei Ivanov: The wikipedia article gives the definition only for vector spaces. I have edited the answer to include this.

Comment: I mean
Definition: A metric space $(X,d)$ is called homogeneous if the group of its isometries acts transitively on $(X,d)$.

Comment: @Ivan: In any case, Sergei Ivanov assures us that Banach spaces are homogeneous. Infinite dimensional Banach spaces are complete and not locally compact. Therefore it would be an example. If you want a concrete example you can take the space of continuous functions on an interval, with supremum norm. 

Comment: I have edited the answer.

Comment: Any topological vector space $V$ is homogeneous viewing addition as an action of the underlying group of $V$ on $V.$